# How to remove the WordPress version from some .css/.js files

Tags: wordpress-version

I know that I can use the following function to remove the version from all `.css` and `.js` files:

```
add_filter( 'style_loader_src', 'sdt_remove_ver_css_js', 9999 );
add_filter( 'script_loader_src', 'sdt_remove_ver_css_js', 9999 );
function sdt_remove_ver_css_js( $src ) {
    if ( strpos( $src, 'ver=' ) )
        $src = remove_query_arg( 'ver', $src );
    return $src;
}
```

But I have some files, for instance `style.css`, in the case of which I want to add a version in the following way:

```
function css_versioning() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'style',
        get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css' ,
        false,
        filemtime( get_stylesheet_directory() . '/style.css' ),
        'all' );
}
```

But the previous function removes also this version. So the question is how to make the two work together?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can check for the current *handle* before removing the version.

Here's an example (untested):

```
add_filter( 'style_loader_src',  'sdt_remove_ver_css_js', 9999, 2 );
add_filter( 'script_loader_src', 'sdt_remove_ver_css_js', 9999, 2 );

function sdt_remove_ver_css_js( $src, $handle ) 
{
    $handles_with_version = [ 'style' ]; // <-- Adjust to your needs!

    if ( strpos( $src, 'ver=' ) && ! in_array( $handle, $handles_with_version, true ) )
        $src = remove_query_arg( 'ver', $src );

    return $src;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Since this question was written, a lot has changed with WordPress. Here is a new way to prevent WordPress from displaying its version number:

```
// remove version from head
remove_action('wp_head', 'wp_generator');

// remove version from rss
add_filter('the_generator', '__return_empty_string');

// remove version from scripts and styles
function remove_version_scripts_styles($src) {
    if (strpos($src, 'ver=')) {
        $src = remove_query_arg('ver', $src);
    }
    return $src;
}
add_filter('style_loader_src', 'remove_version_scripts_styles', 9999);
add_filter('script_loader_src', 'remove_version_scripts_styles', 9999);
```

No editing required. Add to functions.php and done. Or add via simple custom plugin. The choice is yours! :)

[Original article](https://digwp.com/2009/07/remove-wordpress-version-number/)

Comment: isn't this answer directly copied from [here](https://digwp.com/2009/07/remove-wordpress-version-number/)? You should always give credit to original author, unless you wrote that article

Comment: Added the link to the original article. No offense. I just wanted to help people solve the problem. I never took the credit for myself.

Comment: I didn't implied you did, just showed the proper way to do it. that's all :)

Comment: Nice! Unfortunately it doesn't answer OP's question on how to keep it for one certain CSS.

Answer (score 1):

To target a specific file

```
// remove version from scripts and styles
function remove_version_scripts_styles($src) {
    if (strpos($src, 'yourfile.js')) {
        $src = remove_query_arg('ver', $src);
    }
    return $src;
}
add_filter('script_loader_src', 'remove_version_scripts_styles', 9999);
```