# How to remove ver from stylesheet URL?

Tags: theme-development

I am modifying a WordPress theme, but the problem is every time I edit my CSS file via FileZilla and upload it to the server, the CSS file doesn't get updated immediately after browser refresh and it's very frustrating.

I get the idea that the CSS `ver` tag is helping browser not to cache old CSS files, but for the temporary purpose, I would like to disable it.

Can you guys give me a hint, how the code of `style.css?ver=1.0.0` tag command might look like? So that I can reverse engineer it and modify it my self or remove it completely.

Answer (score 2):

You're facing browser caching problem and it's not because of `ver`. Every time you update your CSS or JS files you should hard refresh your browser using `Ctrl + Shift + R` or you can change the `ver` value. If the default `ver` is `ver=1.0.0` then update the `ver` to `ver=1.0.1`. The point is, change the `ver` value to something you didn't set before.

Most of the time the `ver` value comes from theme version. So you can try updating the `Version` parameter in `style.css` or find a theme version constant and update the value if there's any.

And if you still need to remove `ver` then add the following code in your `functions.php` and `ver` will be removed automatically -

```
add_filter( 'style_loader_src', function( $src, $handle ) {
    // If you know the handle
    // if ( 'your-css-handle' === $handle ) {
    //  return remove_query_arg( 'ver', $src );
    // }
    // return $src;
    return remove_query_arg( 'ver', $src );
}, 10, 2 );
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried finding the solution enough, there is already many thread for your solution.
[How to remove version from css](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/233543/how-to-remove-the-wordpress-version-from-some-css-js-files)

To simplify check this.

```
add_filter( 'style_loader_src',  'sdt_remove_ver_css_js', 9999, 2 );

function sdt_remove_ver_css_js( $src, $handle ) 
{
$handles_with_version = [ 'style' ]; // <-- Adjust to your needs!

if ( strpos( $src, 'ver=' ) && ! in_array( $handle, $handles_with_version, true ) )
    $src = remove_query_arg( 'ver', $src );

return $src;
}
```