# How can I remove the Wordpress-Version (?ver=5.x) from my plugin

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, javascript, wp-enqueue-script, footer

I am working on my first plugin that adds a external script to the footer. Wordpress automatically adds the version number at the end, which I'm trying to remove. What I have so far:

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', array($this,'print_code'));

public function print_code(){
         
        $location   =   get_option('location_select');
        $url        =   'https://' . esc_html($location) . '.domain.com/js/script.js';
        wp_enqueue_script('myID', $url, array('jquery'), false, true);


     }
```

This puts out the script correctly, but I still have the version (?ver=5.8) at the end. The false should avoid that, afaik. What am I missing?

Comment: Take a look at this post to see if it helps: [How to remove the Wordpress version from some .css/.js files](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/233543/how-to-remove-the-wordpress-version-from-some-css-js-files)

Comment: That'll work if you need to remove the version from scripts and stylesheets outside your control (ie, loaded by core or 3rd-party themes/plugins), but for OP's question it's as simple as passing `null` as the 4th (`$version`) parameter. [See the docs.](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the 4th parameter from `false` to `null`.

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'myID', $url, array( 'jquery' ), null, true );
```

From the [`wp_enqueue_script()` documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/):

> **$ver**
> (string|bool|null) (Optional) String specifying script version number, if it has one, which is added to the URL as a query string for cache busting purposes. If version is set to false, a version number is automatically added equal to current installed WordPress version. **If set to null, no version is added.**

(emphasis added)

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer! null works of course, I did not read the docs properly -.-

Answer (score 3):

As defined in the [codex](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/),

> If version is set to false, a version number is automatically added equal to current installed WordPress version. If set to null, no version is added.

You're currently setting `false`. You should be setting `null`:

```
wp_enqueue_script('myID', $url, array('jquery'), null, true);
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer! Looks like I am not able to read -.- I set it to null and it works!